# How to store foreach loop values into variable

Tags: php, email, foreach

```
<?php
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT......");

foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) {
    $user_gift = $fivesdraft->recommend_getdetailgift;
    echo $user_gift;
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Television
Computer
Mobile
```

I want to display these values into the below form

```
<input type="hidden" value="???" name="getallgifts" >
```

So that I can get that store into `$_POST['getallgifts']`. In this way, I can send that in email.

Check here the actual code which I'm using in order to achieve my result

**UPDATED**

```
$getallgifts = $_POST['getallgifts[]'];
$message = 'Request From : '.$getallgifts.'
------
<form method="post" action="#" class="getfffff" style="text-align:center;">

<?php
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT *
    -----
);

foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
{
  $user_gift = $fivesdraft->recommend_getdetailgift;
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="' .  $user_gift . '" name="getallgifts[]" >';

}

?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_sum; ?>" name="getwwitdreawv">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<?php
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT  ......   ");
foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $key => $fivesdraft ) {
    $user_gift = $fivesdraft->recommend_getdetailgift;
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="' .  $user_gift . '" name="getallgifts[' . $key . ']" >';
}
?>
```

for retrive the value of the array getallgifts submitted you should try this way

```
  $getallgifts = $_POST['getallgifts'];
  $message =  'Request From : '

  foreach(  $getallgifts as $gift) {
      $message = $message . $gift;
  }
```

Comment: doesn't work... both the above and below answer doesn't work.. The output is displaying Array

Comment: But you need a distinct getallgifts for each row?

Comment: I have update the answer adding a key for the getallgifts array

Comment: yes all rows.. your edited code is not even getting output ..$key=> $fivesdraft edit that..

Comment: Please check my updated question. Yes I tried with that as well but it didn't work either..

Comment: Please echo/show  the content of $_Post[] you obtain with my answer. I need to know the key value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90471/discussion-between-shoeb-and-scaisedge).

Comment: array(4) { ["getallgifts"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(22) "e-voucher - € 0.01 " [1]=> string(22) "e-voucher - € 0.01 " } ["getwwitdreawv"]=> string(5) "10.01" ["getwwitdreass"]=> string(8) "Withdraw" ["wwwgetsignupsaverecommend"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: The last comment you is for ?

Comment: seem in your $_POST you have an 'getallgifts' entry equal to an array of 2. show thsi  content  please

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
}

Comment: I'm sorry but is not clear. You have an array of 2 or an array of 1? and you in the prevoius comment have entry non t related with the code you show in question

Comment: I have update the answer please provide to configure your test case in the way suggested,  Or explain better your code..

Comment: Well I just want to tell you that there are other _POST values as well which are getting excuted properly and I'm receiving the fine ouput in my email as well. Only this I'm not getting..

Comment: I don't understand why in the ["getallgifts"] index [0] you have string(22) "e-voucher - € 0.01 "  and not the value i suppose is  in $fivesdrafts.I'sorry but what you have for sure in $fivesdrafts try echo/var_dump the value of $fivesdrafts

Comment: I'm having two values 1) e-voucher - €  0.01  2) e-voucher - €  0.01 .. These two should echo in the email as well... [but it is not getting echoed in the Email but on the frontend it is working fine..

Comment: When you refer to Email you mean this value are not assigned to the $message in the top of the updated code frame?.

Comment: Exactly..That's what I'm trying to make you understand

Comment: I have update the answer. I hope it is the right time

Comment: I was focused on how to send the data with the submit and I had missed $message code in the frame added. Well I'm glad

Answer (score 1):

Change this part:

```
$user_gift = $fivesdraft->recommend_getdetailgift;
echo $user_gift;
```

To this:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$fivesdraft->recommend_getdetailgift.'"
 name="getallgifts[]">'
```

This way, you'll have an element in your `$_POST` array named `[getallgifts]` that will have an array inside it, with every instance of this `input` you'll `echo`.